# Jmeter - Table of "Count of Request" vs "Number of request less than (sec)"

Tags: jmeter

I need to produce a table that looks like this:

[image]

I look at the available graphs and I don't know which one I can use to get the table.

Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at logparser from Microsoft (free download) to process the raw JTL file to produce your query output.  This is a pretty straightforward query with a count and a group clause.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any existing JMeter test elements or plugins which are capable of producing the table you're looking for, you will need to [create your own JMeter plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugin-development).

Alternative options are in:

1. JMeter .jtl result files are basically [CSV files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) so you can use [MS Excel](https://office.live.com/start/Excel.aspx) or equivalent for parsing response times and counting the requests which fall into this or that category
2. You can use [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and [Groovy language](https://groovy-lang.org/) somewhere in [tearDown Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group) to count the occurrences of response times. Something like:

   ```
   def responseTimes = new File('result.jtl').readLines().tail().collect { line -> line.split(',')[1] as int }

   println('Total responses: ' + responseTimes.size())

   1.upto(10, { threshold ->
       println('Responses less than ' + threshold + ' seconds: ' + responseTimes.findAll { responseTime -> responseTime < threshold * 1000 }.size())
   })
   ```

   [image]

   you will get output like:

   [image]

Comment: I ended up using excel pivot table to get a count vs the elapsed time.  I still have to aggregate and round up to the next sec.  Look ok so far.  Thanks very much for your response.